# Can I run a npm module with Grunt?

Tags: ember.js, npm, gruntjs

my question is simple: can I run a npm module with gruntjs? I want to run [ember-precompile](https://npmjs.org/package/ember-precompile) from grunt. Or is there any possibility to run a bash or python script from gruntjs? Since I didn't see any grunt plugins for this module I don't know how to automate the template compilation (not just semi-automate,by writing a bash script that will run it with the specific arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a grunt plugin specifically for this task: [grunt-ember-templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates)

You could either dig into the internals of what I did or just incorporate it directly into your grunt script.

Comment: Thanks, I used this solution, since it suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to go the bash route, I've had good success with @sindresorhus's [grunt-shell](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell).

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this plan of action since it kind of defeats the purpose of grunt but hey, it works.